# Should email receipts (for events) be recorded as an activity for the recipient?

Tags: reports, receipts

Activity reports with a filter of Receipt do not show receipts sent

Should they be shown?  Is there another way to see a report on whether a receipt email is actually sent?

[image]

Search kit also does not show such activities
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a separate activity for the receipt email. Unless something is broken, you would assume that the event registration activity would also cover the confirmation email.

Comment: The need is to verify that confirmation emails are being sent out.  There is a receipt activity (actually 2 of them).

Comment: You might want to look at the Transactional Emails extension for that:
https://civicrm.org/extensions/transactional-emails

Comment: ahh, should have thought of that